# Edit and reuse the formula part of the call for a model in R

Tags: r

I have fit a neural net in R:

```
model = nnet(f1/max(f1)~n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8+n9+n10+n11+n12,data=md,size=3)
```

From the model object I can extract the formula of the call, `model$call$formula`, which returns an object of type `call` and appears to be a list of length 3.  I know I can use `as.formula()` on the `call` object in the `nnet()` call but I don't know how to edit it first.

What I want to do is modify the formula and then pass it back to `nnet()`.  Specifically, I'd like to be able to change the dependent variable and add or remove dependent variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do it "manually" without `update.formula`. 
I guess using `update.formula` might be easier, but still i give you another way:

```
## your formula
f.example <- x ~ n1 + n2
## you can extract each member of the formula with [[2/1/3]] 
f.left.side <-as.character(f.example[[2]])  # "x"
f.middle <- as.character(f.example[[1]])  # "~"
f.right.side <- as.character(f.example[[3]])  # "n1 + n2"
## you do your change, e.g:
f.right.side.new <- "n1 + n3"
## you rebuild your formula, first as a character (%s for string), then as a formula
f.new <- sprintf("%s ~ %s", f.left.side, f.right.side.new)
f.new <- as.formula(f.new)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`update.formula`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/update.formula.html):

> update.formula is used to update model formulae. This typically involves adding or dropping terms, but updates can be more general.

Here are some examples you can look at using variables from `mtcars`:

```
f1 <- mpg ~ cyl + wt
f2 <- update(f1, . ~ . + am)
f2
## mpg ~ cyl + wt + am
f3 <- update(f2, hp ~ .)
f3
## hp ~ cyl + wt + am
f4 <- update(f3, mpg ~ hp)
f4
## mpg ~ hp
```