# create a reusable part in R formula

Tags: r

That is not a duplicate of this ([Edit and reuse the formula part of the call for a model in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381410/edit-and-reuse-the-formula-part-of-the-call-for-a-model-in-r)) but rather an extension.

So let's say I have several regression models to test. I also have a set of socio demographic variables that I want to add to each model to control for them.

```r
m1 <- lm(a~b)
m1_full <- lm(a~b+age+gender+income)
m2 <- lm(c~d)
m2_full <- lm(c~d+age+gender+income)
```

Is there a way to store (`age+gender+income`) and add it to some models?

Something like that (in pseudocode):

```r
ses <- age+gender+income
m1 <- lm(a~b)
m1_full <- lm(a~b+... ses)
m2 <- lm(c~d)
m2_full <- lm(c~d+...ses)
```

Comment: does this answer work https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371468/2994949

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can just `paste` everything together into a formula. Here's a function that would do the whole process:

```r
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(age = rpois(200,45),
                 gender = rbinom(200,1,0.5),
                 income = rnorm(200,30000,10000),
                 a = rnorm(200),
                 b = rnorm(200),
                 c = rnorm(200),
                 d = rnorm(200))
ses <- c("age", "gender", "income")
get_lm_model <- function(df, outcome_var, pred_var, ses) {
    fm <- as.formula(paste(outcome_var, "~", pred_var, "+", paste(ses, collapse = " + ")))
    lm(fm, data = df)
} 

get_lm_model(df, "a", "b", ses)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = fm, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)            b          age       gender       income  
#>   3.345e-01   -9.516e-02   -3.748e-03   -7.033e-02   -6.718e-06
get_lm_model(df, "c", "d", ses)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = fm, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)            d          age       gender       income  
#>   2.775e-01    5.570e-02   -4.564e-03   -5.359e-02   -5.898e-06
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>